# How to post a file to an image hosting service in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, webclient

Scenario:

localhost receives the current HttpRequest with 3 hidden inputs and a posted file.  I must then forward this form data to an external image host and get the response.

Answer (score 1):

See the System.Net.[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) and related classes. You can use them to create a request to the remote server and handle the response. Also get [Fiddle](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)r to help you replicate what the browser sends.

Answer (score 0):

I hate doing this.  It wastes my server's bandwidth and ties up IIS threads as well as using my server's CPU.  It sucks and it's worth avoiding at all cost.  Many services like, one that comes to mind is fliqz, provide a mechanism such that the files are uploaded directly from the client to their server (bypassing yours) and then they make a request to your server passing it various info on the query string.